Apathetic divorced film star with daughter
The film starts with the protagonist lying in bed while a pair of young identical twin women are pole-dancing for him. In the same scene or a later one he tries touching one of them, who pushes him away, reminding him of her name. Apparently he's involved with her sister but can't keep track or doesn't care.
He is a film star. In one scene, the protagonist gets a question from an interviewer regarding some kind of deeper meaning of his character of the film he is playing in and the protagonist's reaction - it was either struggling to find an answer or just saying something disappointing like "not really" - shows how little he is involved personally or intellectually in his work. But he is very charming while doing so.
The protagonist has a daughter with a divorced wife. He shares custody. At the end of the film it seems that he decides to spend time with his daughter. Although it might as well be that he decides to spend me-time, taking a break from stardom. In either case, it seems to be a kind of "drive away in car" end scene.
The language of the film seems broken, natural, naturalist, naturalistic or realistic - I'm not sure what the word is or whether it exists. Dialogue seems meaningless at times.
I thought the protagonist was portrayed by Brad Pitt or Leonardo DiCaprio but looking through either filmography I seem to be mistaken.
I think the film was made after 2005.
What's the film I'm looking for?

Sofia Coppola's Somewhere from 2010 with Stephen Dorff. 

Hollywood actor Johnny Marco, nested in his luxury hotel of choice, is a stimulated man. Drinking, parties and women keep a creeping boredom under wraps in between jobs. He is the occasional father of a bright girl, Cleo, who may be spoiled but doesn't act it. When Cleo's mother drops her off and leaves town, Johnny brings her along for the ride, but can he fit an 11-year-old girl into his privileged lifestyle?

The scenes you mentioned are there, including the pole-dancing twins. The daughter was played by Elle Fanning. Here's the trailer:




Thanks for the correction, Will. Fanning is talented, but she still has a long way to go before netting two Super Bowl rings. ;)
